# Why is Visual Studio 2019 installer not working on my computer?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2019 to do a project. But whenever I double click the vs_community installer, it displays preparation window and then it disappears. To solve the problem, I upgraded all applications offered by Windows Operating system and turned off all defenders on the Windows, rebooted the Windows10 and confirm that the computer has enough space but it didn't help.

Here is the screenshot for explanation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtxCC.jpg)

As you can see the installer seems to prepare for the installation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG2fE.jpg)

Then, it disappears.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

well, are you using the latest version if yes then try to downgrade the version but before downgrading Please make sure you have installed all dependency of Vs such as the .NET Framework? Please check the installer details to make sure that you have that same .net framework that will be needed to complete that installation process. Well, thank you.